# Show some navigation pages just in breadcrumbs not in top menu in zf2

Tags: menu, navigation, zend-framework2, breadcrumbs

I have a navigation and use it for breadcrumbs. I want to use it for top menu too , but I don't want to show my products in top menu.
How Can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a custom attribute while defining the array in the module.config.php -

Eg:

```
array(
    'label' => 'Product List',
    'route' => 'product',
    'action' => 'index',
    'resource' => 'Product\Controller\Product:index',
    'top_menu' => '0',
),
```

For the rest of the arrays set the `top_menu` attribute to `1`.

**In the partial file of top-menu, check -**

```
<?php foreach ($this->container as $page) {
    [...]

    if($page->get('top_menu') == '1') {
        //Code to display the menu.
    }

    [...]    
} ?>
```

I hope it gives some idea.